# How can I disable a plugin in Health Check mode if there's a critical error?

Tags: plugins, errors, troubleshooting, site-health-widget

The normal approach to this would be to rename the plugin directory, but that would affect the live site as well. I can rename `health-check-troubleshooting-mode.php` but the critical error just resumes once I re-enable health check mode.

What's the proper way to resolve this?